# Build code in vscode using external http server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Our code building process is done via an http server which starts the build process after receiving a project uuid from the build command. Once the server starts the compilation, GCC compatible output can be fetched from it.
Note: only my extension is aware of the project uuid which is different per workspace.
AFAIU I can implement it by:

1. programmatically adding a task which will call a script with the correct workspace uuid. Is this possible?
2. Having my extension manage the build process. This seems to be far from supported.

Bottom line, I'm trying to avoid asking the user to add anything to the configuration files and I want to completely manage the build process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't find a suitable only vscode solution I did the following:
Defined a helper script which I executed as the task. The helper script was respojnsible for the communication against the HTTP server.
I registered the task using vscode.workspace.registerTaskProvider API, and made sure to register it only after figuring out the UUID.
Then in the task itself I executed the helper script.
(A nice task register example can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/task-provider-sample)